# How to fix angular-translate showing translation key on webpage on load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, translation

I am using [angular-translate](https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate) for i8n in my project. 
I am using ansynchronous url-loader to load my translation tables.

```
$translate.useUrlLoader(myUrl)
```

The translate *directives* and *filters* both return the key which I am translating until the translation tables are loaded.

```
<a ng-bind="translation.key | translate"></a>
<a translate="translation.key></a>
```

Both the above display 'translation.key' on the webpage until the translation tables are loaded.

**NOTE**: 
I have reasons to not listen on $translationChangeSuccess event.

---

> I am looking for *either* of the two solutions
>
> - Synchronously load translation tables from URL.
> - Don't show translated text until translation tables are completely loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue when dealing with asynchronous execution. angular-translate now comes with a `translate-cloak` directive that helps you out preventing FOUCs. You can read about it here: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading#asynchronous-loading_fouc---flash-of-untranslated-content